# WebSocket Single Read Sampler, Websocket I/O error, WebSocket I/O error: Socket is closed,

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am getting the following error in Jmeter: (For some time it runs fine then after some time it started giving error, not sure why)

Response code:, WebSocket Single Read Sampler, Websocket I/O error, WebSocket I/O error: Socket is closed,

Please let me know if there is any solution which can be implemented to avoid this or any suggestion for probable root cause?

Is this issue related to server-side issue

Answer (score 0):

As per [Closing the Connection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7) chapter of the WebSocket protocol specification:

> To *Close the WebSocket Connection*, an **endpoint closes the
> underlying TCP connection**.  An endpoint SHOULD use a method that
> cleanly closes the TCP connection, as well as the TLS session, if
> applicable, discarding any trailing bytes that may have been
> received.  An endpoint MAY close the connection via any means
> available when necessary, such as when under attack.

> **The underlying TCP connection, in most normal cases, SHOULD be closed
> first by the server**, so that it holds the TIME_WAIT state and not the
> client (as this would prevent it from re-opening the connection for 2
> maximum segment lifetimes (2MSL), while there is no corresponding
> server impact as a TIME_WAIT connection is immediately reopened upon
> a new SYN with a higher seq number).  In abnormal cases (such as not
> having received a TCP Close from the server after a reasonable amount
> of time) a client MAY initiate the TCP Close.  As such, when a server
> is instructed to *Close the WebSocket Connection* it SHOULD initiate
> a TCP Close immediately, and when a client is instructed to do the
> same, it SHOULD wait for a TCP Close from the server.

So you need to check your endpoint logs in order to determine the reason (unless you're not closing the connection on your own)

It might be the case that the endpoint is not [properly configured for high loads](https://dzone.com/articles/load-balancing-of-websocket-connections) and doesn't accept high number of connections or it's get overloaded in terms of CPU, RAM and Network IO so it worth checking these metrics using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)